# PHP foreach loop is taking time to load thousands of table data in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, foreach

On a page I have 8500 Employees shown in table data in the form of `<tr>` and `<td>`.
The Name of the Employees shown with a checkbox in front of each name of employee. 
When I click on checkboxes the I insert the employees data (Employee Name and Employee Id) session.

Everything is working fine but the problem is when I click on check All checkbox then all the employees checkboxes are selected then there is a button named as "View Selected". On the click of this button I want to all the selected employees. When user click on this button a new child window will be opened with selected employee data in the form table row and data.

I am doing this but using session which I have created on the click of employees checkboxes.

Everything is working on Mozilla Firefox but when I check this of Google Chrome then it is not working and I am getting the browser message KillPages or Wait. The loader image of Chrome is shown but data is not loading.

My new child window page code is this where I am reading the session and running the for-each loop to print the data in the form of table data.

```
    <?php require_once("../../includes/global.php");
    $sessionName = rq('sessionName');
    $employees = $session->read($sessionName);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITEURL_PAGE; ?  
  >configuration/js/attendancePolicy.js"></script>

    <div style="width: 100%;">
  <?php if(strpos($sessionName, 'location') !== false) {?>
  <h3 style="padding-left:10px;">View <?php echo LOCATION_DISPLAY_NAME?>s</h3>
  <?php } else {?>
  <h3 style="padding-left:10px;">View <?php echo  
  us(substr(str_replace('ot_','',$sessionName), 0, -3))?></h3>
  <?php }?>
  <?php         
         $totalEmployees = $session->check($sessionName) ? (int)count($session->read($sessionName)) : 0;        
        ?>
  <form id="updateEmployeesForm" name="updateEmployeesForm" method="post"   action="saveAttendancePolicy.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidAction" value="addNewPolicy_step3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionName" id="sessionName" value="<?php echo $sessionName?>" />
    <?php 
$styleTab = '';
$style='';
if($totalEmployees > 30){
    $styleTab = 'border-bottom: none;';
    $style = 'overflow:auto; height: 230px !important; border-bottom: 4px solid #2C90D3;';
}
//for over time policy only
$functionSuffix = '';
if($sessionName == 'ot_locations_cb' || $sessionName == 'ot_divisions_cb' || $sessionName == 'ot_departments_cb' || $sessionName == 'ot_employees_cb') {
    $functionSuffix = 'overTimePolicy';
}

$where  = rq('where');
$employeeLoadPage = ($sessionName == 'ot_employees_cb')?'otpolicy_ajax':'';
if(stripos($sessionName, 'employee') > -1) {
    $js = "closeClildWindow('', 'employeeDiv', 'yes','".$employeeLoadPage."');";
} else if(stripos($sessionName, 'location') > -1) {
    $js = "searchPolicySpecificNew('', 'locations', 'locationDiv', {'session':'yes'},'".$functionSuffix."'); updateChildPolicyNew('".$sessionName."', 'yes','".$functionSuffix."');";
} else if(stripos($sessionName, 'division') > -1) {
    $js = "searchPolicySpecificNew('', 'divisions', 'divisionDiv', {'session':'yes'},'".$functionSuffix."'); updateChildDepartmentPolicyNew('".$sessionName."', 'locations_cb', 'yes','".$functionSuffix."');";
} else if(stripos($sessionName, 'department') > -1) {
    $js = "searchPolicySpecificNew('', 'departments', 'departmentDiv', {'session':'yes'},'".$functionSuffix."'); updateChildjobTitlePolicy('".$sessionName."', 'divisions_cb', 'locations_cb', '','".$functionSuffix."');";
}

if($where == 'viewEmp') {
    if($sessionName == 'ot_employees_cb') {
        $js="getSelectedEmployeesNew('OT');";
    } else {
        $js="getSelectedEmployeesNew();";
    }
}
?>
    <div class="totalRecord" style="float:right; width:99%;text-align:right; margin-top: 5px;">
      <label>Total Record(s) :<?php echo $totalEmployees ?></label>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0 2% 0 2%; width: 96%;" class="div_row">
      <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="bdrtable" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col" colspan="5"> <input type="checkbox" name="viewCheckAllName" id="viewCheckAllName" <?php if($totalEmployees > 0) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> class="class_parent_pop" onClick="sessionCheckBox('class_parent_pop', '<?php echo $sessionName?>_pop', 'parent', this);"   />
              Check All </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 2%; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%; width:96%;<?php echo $style;?>" class="div_row">
      <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="bdrtable" style="<?php echo $styleTab?>">
        <?php if($totalEmployees > 0) { ?>
        <tr>
          <?php $i=1; 
                    foreach($employees as $key=>$employeeArr) {             
                ?>
          <td align="left" width="33%"><?php echo $i; ?> </td>
          <?php 
                        if($i%3 == 0 && $i != $totalEmployees) {
                            echo '</tr><tr>';
                        }
                    $i++; 
                    }           
                    if($totalEmployees%3 != 0) {                                
                        for ($x=($totalEmployees%3); $x < 3; $x++) {                                            
                            echo '<td align="left" width="33%">&nbsp;</td>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
        </tr>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo "No Data Found"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="div_row" style="text-align: right; width: 96%; margin:0 2%;">
      <?php if($totalEmployees > 0) {?>
      <input type="button" name="updateEmp" id="updateEmp" value="Update" class="submit" onClick="sessionCheckBoxPopupUpdate('<?php echo $sessionName?>_pop', '<?php echo $sessionName?>');<?php echo $js; ?>" />
      <?php } ?>
      <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" class="submit" onClick="javascript:window.close();" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the foreach loop that is slow, 8500 is good number of data to load, you might want to page the results.

Why don't you try the same query using phpmyadmin and see the time taken.

Comment: @Aaron.... Actually I am getting data from java services, not from any query from my side.

Comment: @user2717089 You must implement Pagination. What if an office has 100,000 employees ?

Comment: @Aaron.... Actually I am getting data from java services, not from any query from my side. I am agree with that it is not foreach loop which is taking time because if I print directly the counting of this loop with a variable incremented with loop then it is working fine and print from 1 to 8500. But if I use any HTML element like table tr td or div then it is creating problem only on google chrome

Comment: @2-Stroker... Thanks for your comment and your point id right but as per the current scenario I can not change the functionality. This is as per our application requirement and it is throughout the application. We are having offices less than 10000 employees.

Comment: Can anybody please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi, you want to try using client side technology instead? since your data source cannot be controlled. They will load the data and the HTML stuff processed later, instead of waiting on the server side to spit out all those HTML stuff...

You can try using flexigrid, datatable or something like that for rapid prototype

Comment: you can also generate 8500 HTML inputs without the DB data using the  foreach loop to confirm that the HTML is killing your page performance...